# How to change theme of the keyboard for android in react-native app?

Tags: android, react-native, keyboard, themes, textinput

I have an app on react-native with two themes: light and dark. And it looks not so nice when the keyboard in the light colours appears in the dark theme. I need to change the theme of the keyboard depends on my app theme. On IOS it is possible to make with keyboardAppearance(enum('default', 'light', 'dark')) property from TextInput https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput.html#keyboardappearance. But it is not working on Android. Does somebody know a good way to do it?

[image]

Comment: The theme of android's keyboard is so diverse, how could you choose a theme to fit so many kind of keyboard? In most situation, keyboard shows what user have set for default(On Android).

Comment: It's not dependant on react-native

Comment: Why does it depend?

Answer (score -4):

you can find a solution for this issue at https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput.html
be careful